# Centrifugal Space Station design

Tags: space-station, station-keeping

If a Space Station designed around centrifugal forces being essential for gravity was to be constructed similar to the fans of a helicopter blade like the image below, how would it differ from a regular torus design of space settlement?[image]

Would building off to the sides cause the centrifuge to dis-align and knock it off course if it was orbiting a planetary body at a stable orbit?
Please provide serious answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is purely a question about the difference between linear momentum and angular momentum, and not particularly about *space exploration* at all. The question would be identical if you replace the word "space station" with "dumbbell", and so I think this is off-topic for this site. Physics SE is better, though it is likely to have an answer there already. Hint, the answer is no, it would not dis-align and knock it off course. The isolated object's linear and angular momenta would not couple.